# Override toString() for an iterating variable

Tags: java, oop, overriding

I wish to modify the toString() method so that my print statement returns "some random text"

```
HashSet<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<List<Integer>>(){
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "some random text";
    }
};

//Code that assigns some values to the set variable 
for(List<Integer>subSequence:set){
    System.out.println(subSequence.toString());
} //Still prints the values in the Lists
```

How can I get "some random text" to print for every List in the set?

Comment: But since the content is `Integer` that is not possible.

Comment: "How can I get "some random text" to print for every List in the set" `System.out.println("some random text");`

Comment: The less flippant answer is `System.out.println(someMethodBuildingTheStringYouWant(subSequence))`.

Comment: *"How can I get "some random text" to print for every List in the set?"* Why would you want to?

Comment: Just for the sake of better understanding of how overloading works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the `toString()` method of the anonymous `HashSet` class.
While you invoke in your code the `toString()` method of the elements of the `HashSet` : `List<Integer>`.
The overriden method will so not be used.

> How can I get "some random text" to print for every List in the set?

You cannot with the actual method as `List` implementations have their own `toString()` implementation.

You could create and use your own `List` implementation to be able to override `toString` but it seems over complicated for such a simple need.

If I were you, I would define the `toString()` implementation of the anonymous `HashSet` class to iterate on the elements and I would display the message for each one :

```
HashSet<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<List<Integer>>() {
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    if (size() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<List<Integer>> it = iterator();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        it.next();
        sb.append("some random text");

        if (!it.hasNext()) {
          return sb.append(']').toString();
        }
        sb.append(',').append(' ');
    }
  }
};
```